# SQL - Find AT LEAST TWO DISTINCT / SEPARATE / DIFFERENT values on another Table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, postgresql

While taking an Online database course (for beginner) a problem has came to my attention, where I had to find queries involving ...**AT LEAST TWO DISTINCT values**... For example,

the COMPANY database in the ELMASRI book which states: **Find all employee who work on at least two distinct projects**. And the solution (which works great) is

```
SELECT DISTINCT LName FROM Employee e1
JOIN Works_On AS w1 ON (e1.Ssn = w1.Essn)
JOIN Works_On AS w2 ON (e1.Ssn = w2.Essn)
WHERE w1.Pno <> w2.Pno
```

Similarly in case of the STUDENT/COURSE database (i forgot the source): **Find the Student_ID of the Students who take at least two distinct Courses**. And the solution looks also simple (though its not tested)

```
SELECT e1.Student_ID FROM Enroll AS e1, Enroll AS e2
WHERE e1.Student_ID = e2.Student_ID
AND e1.Course_ID <> e2.Course_ID
```

In my problem, I have to **Find the name and customer ID of those customers who have accounts in at least two branches of distinct types  (i.e., which do not have the same Branch Type).**
from the following table (MySql)

```
CUSTOMER:            BRANCH:             ACCOUNT:
Cust_ID  Lname       Br_ID  Br_Type      Acc_Num  Br_ID  Cust_ID  Balance
-------  ------      -----  -------      -------  -----  -------  -------
1        Mr.A        10     big          1001     10     1        2000
2        Mr.B        11     small        1002     11     1        2500  
3        Mr.C        12     big          1003     13     1        3000
4        Mr.D        13     small        1004     12     2        4000 
                                         1005     13     3        4500
                                         1006     10     4        5000
                                         1007     12     4        6000
```

Result Table should look like the following:

```
Lname  Cust_ID
-----  -------
Mr.A   1
```

Only Mr.A has account in a branch whose type is 'big' as well as in a branch whose type is 'small'

I tried the following which didnt work

```
SELECT DISTINCT c1.Lname, a1.Cust_ID FROM Customer AS c1
JOIN Account a1 ON (c1.Cust_ID=a1.Cust_ID)
JOIN Branch b1 ON (a1.Br_ID=b1.Br_ID)
JOIN Branch b2 ON (a1.Br_ID=b2.Br_ID)
WHERE b1.Br_Type<>b2.Br_Type;
```

What am I exactly doing wrong? Sorry for such a long description but i wanted to make sure that the question is understandable and a little explanation on < > part will be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you are using MySQL then why did you add the Postgres tag?

Comment: actually the solutions has to work both in MySql and Postgresql, forgot to mention that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to pull 2 different Branch records off the same Account record - but that can't happen.  What you want is to search on 2 different Account records with associated Branches of a different type:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c1.Lname, a1.Cust_ID FROM Customer AS c1
JOIN Account a1 ON (c1.Cust_ID=a1.Cust_ID)
JOIN Account a2 ON (c1.Cust_ID=a2.Cust_ID)
JOIN Branch b1 ON (a1.Br_ID=b1.Br_ID)
JOIN Branch b2 ON (a2.Br_ID=b2.Br_ID)
WHERE b1.Br_Type<>b2.Br_Type;
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0db68a/3)

A more efficient approach that gives the same result, would be to use GROUP BY and `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Br_Type) >= 2` - which is what @GordonLindoff proposed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your query is the two `on` conditions.  They are returning the same row in `branch`, because the join conditions are the same.

In any case, I think there is a better way to think about these types of queries (what I call "set--sets" queries).  Think of these as aggregation.  Aggregation at the customer level, then using the `having` clause to filter the customers:

```
SELECT c.Lname, a.Cust_ID
FROM Customer AS c JOIN
     Account a
     ON c.Cust_ID = a.Cust_ID JOIN
     Branch b
     ON a.Br_ID = b.Br_ID
GROUP BY c.Lname, a.Cust_ID
HAVING count(distinct b.br_type) > 1;
```